# Variable types in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm building a site that allows people to book events. I want to be able to automatically remove an event from the site when it reaches capacity.

I have a registration table, which stores the delegate_id and instance_id, so I can see who has booked what for where. instance_id links to the instance table, which stores the event information - place, date, and capacity.

Now, it seems that what I should be able to do is get the number of delegates registered for a given instance, and compare that to the capacity for that instance, and then use those numbers to have the site display the event or not. So I have these queries:

```
//Delegates Query
$qRegs = "SELECT COUNT(delegate_id) FROM registration
WHERE registration.instance_id = $instance_id";
$rRegs = mysqli_query($dbc,$qRegs);
$registrations = mysqli_fetch_object($rRegs);

//Capacity Query
$qCap = "SELECT instance_cap FROM instance
WHERE instance_id = $instance_id";
$rCap = mysqli_query($dbc,$qCap);
$capacity = mysqli_fetch_object($rCap);
```

So I can then simply calculate availability thus:

```
$availability = $capacity - $registrations;
```

However, this throws an error: **Notice: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int**. I've tried typecasting the variables with `(int)` but that makes no difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Read the documentation for mysqli_fetch_object @ http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your two objects don't actually contain the single field.  They are objects that contain field names with what is in your query.

You will need to give your first select statement a name for the `COUNT` operation.  For example, let's say you call it registrations in the query.

`$availability = $capacity->instance_cap - $registrations->registrations;`

For more clarification, you may want to read the documentation on [mysqli_fetch_object located here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php).

Comment: Got it, working, thank you - I'll accept when it lets me.

Comment: You're welcome.  I remember thinking the same thing when I was using fetch_object.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning objects.

So these will be `StdClasses` get the actual value using below

```
$qCap = "SELECT instance_cap FROM instance
         WHERE instance_id = $instance_id";
$rCap = mysqli_query($dbc,$qCap);
$row = mysqli_fetch_object($rCap);
$capacity= $row->instance_cap;
```

You can do this for both queries

Answer (score 1):

```
$capacity = mysqli_fetch_object($rCap);
```

fetches an object. You need to grab any columns you want to use:

```
$rCap = mysqli_query($dbc,$qCap);
$capacity = mysqli_fetch_object($rCap);
print_r($capacity->instance_cap);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for the records to be returned as objects so you have to reference them as such. I  would highly suggest you cast your fields as well for clarity

```
//Delegates Query
$qRegs = "SELECT COUNT(delegate_id) AS count FROM registration
WHERE registration.instance_id = $instance_id";
$rRegs = mysqli_query($dbc,$qRegs);
$registrations = mysqli_fetch_object($rRegs);

//Capacity Query
$qCap = "SELECT instance_cap FROM instance
WHERE instance_id = $instance_id";
$rCap = mysqli_query($dbc,$qCap);
$capacity = mysqli_fetch_object($rCap);

$availability = $capacity->instance_cap - $registrations->count;
```